# The window size when using window.open in Edge's App Mode

Tags: microsoft-edge

When using the window.open function in a browser opened in Edge's App Mode,
the window size becomes smaller than the specified height and width.
What could be the cause?
Also, the maximum height is limited to 1033px

The cause of the window size becoming smaller than the specified value and its possible solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's by design. I also test in Chrome and it's the same behavior. Edge and Chrome both use chromium, if you think that's an issue, you can provide feedback on [this forum](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

For the maximum height limitation, I think that depends on your monitor's height.